# Рекурсивный парсер html с помощью бибилотеки htmlcxx

Tags: html, c++, рекурсия

Доброго времени суток! Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что не так с рекурсией. Не работает правильно, и всё тут! С помощью рекурсивной функции ищу тэг с заданным значением заданного атрибута. Однако, функция всегда возвращает, что такого атрибута нет, хотя я точно знаю, что есть. Из этого делаю вывод, что неверно работает рекурсивный обход. Вот код:

```
int depthSearch(tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node> const & dom,
                tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node>::iterator &returnIt,
                tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node>::iterator &currentIterator,
                string tagName,
                string attributeName,
                string attrContent)
{
    int errorCode = 0;
    //return fixed-depth iterator to the first node at a given depth for given iterator
    tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin_fixed (currentIterator, 0);
    tree<htmlcxx::HTML::Node> currDom;

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < dom.number_of_children(it); i++ )
    {
        //return child node of current node
        currDom = dom.child(it, i);
        //Return leaf iterator to the first leaf of the subtree at the given node.
        currentIterator = currDom.head;

        if (currDom.number_of_children(it) > 0)
        {
            errorCode = depthSearch(currDom, returnIt, currentIterator, tagName, attributeName, attrContent);
            if (errorCode == 0)
            {
                returnIt = it;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorCode = GoToTagWithAttr(currDom.begin_fixed(currentIterator, 0),
                                        tagName,
                                        attributeName,
                                        attrContent);
            if (errorCode == 0)
            {
                returnIt = it;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }
    return 1;
}
```

Суть алгоритма: идём по детям узлов, доходим до самого глубокого, начинаем проверять, есть ли в нём нужные атрибуты. Дальше, если нет - откатываемся рекурсивно назад и снова проверяем. Если нашли нужный узел с нужным атрибутом - тут же выходим и запоминаем указатель найдённого тэга.

Ссылка на документацию библиотеки: [Документация к htmlcxx](http://tree.phi-sci.com/doxygen/html/classtree.html#e1dbb80115ba483e37d081a2256c239b).

Статья по поводу использования итераторов: [htmlcxx базовое описание и основные приёмы использования](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/74320/).

А вот просто несколько ссылок на то, как люди используют библиотеку:

[htmlcxx c++ crawling html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081181/htmlcxx-c-crawling-html)

[htmlcxx API usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480570/htmlcxx-api-usage)

[htmlcxx - html and css APIs for C++](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: а то, что вы ищете элемент с заданными атрибутами только дойдя до "листьев" дерева, - правильно? Так и задумано? Потому как в случае, если есть ответвления от какого-либо из "узлов", то код с вызовом GoToTagWithAttr() в этом узле уже не выполняется никогда.

Comment: @margosh, нет, мне нужно обходить все ответвления, потому что нужный тэг сидит достаточно глубоко и его невозможно получить с помощью индексов первого уровня(((

Comment: Я имела ввиду, что в текущем алгоритме вы обойдете только те элементы дерева, у которых нет потомков, все элементы, у которых потомки есть, - проверены на совпадение атрибутов не будут. Кроме того, мне кажется, что в случае успешного нахождения атрибутов в одном из таких потомков, Вы затираете итератор на него, так как, при возвращении из функции в "родителе", Вы присваиваете параметру родительский итератор.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам необходимо проверять каждый из узлов дерева на совпадение параметров, независимо от того, есть ли у этого узла потомки, то в данной функции проверку на подходящие атрибуты нужно произвести после цикла for:

```
...
for{
...
}
errorCode = GoToTagWithAttr(currDom.begin_fixed(currentIterator, 0),
                            tagName,
                            attributeName,
                            attrContent);
if (errorCode == 0)
{
   returnIt = it;
   return 0;
}
rerurn 1;
```

Кроме того, для случая, когда у узла есть потомки, и в одном из них нашелся нужный атрибут, если вы хотите передавать наверх итератор именно на тот потомок, строка "returnIt = it;" - лишняя :

```
...
if (currDom.number_of_children(it) > 0)
{
   errorCode = depthSearch(currDom, returnIt, currentIterator, tagName, attributeName, attrContent);
   if (errorCode == 0)
   {
      return 0;
   }
}
else{
...
}
```

Возможно, проблемы в этом, к сожалению дописать Ваш код, чтобы проверить свои гипотизы у меня сейчас нет возможности.

Comment: ваше предположение было неверным. Внизу написала код, который хоть как-то работает.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому пригодиться. Немного "подделал" оригинальный htmlcxx.
https://github.com/Ruzzz/htmlcxx
Обязательно смотреть /test/test.cpp

Пример:

```
std::string html(...ВАШ HTML с ссылкам...);
ParserDom parser;
Tree domTree = parser.parseTree(html);
Tree::pre_order_iterator it = domTree.begin();

std::vector<std::string> links;
std::string href;
std::for_each(it, domTree.end(), [&links, &href](Node &node)
{
    if (node.isTag() 
            && (node.tagName() == "a")
            && (node.parseAttributes() > 0)
            && (node.attribute("href", href)))
        links.push_back(href);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как этот код работает, но только для примера с небольшой вложенностью. Он почему-то в упор не хочет работать на примерах реальных html-страниц!!!

```
void walk_tree( tree<HTML::Node> const & dom , std::string tagName, std::string attrName, std::string attrContent)
{
    tree<HTML::Node>::iterator it = dom.begin();

    if (strcasecmp(it->tagName().c_str(), tagName.c_str()) == 0) {
        it->parseAttributes();
        if (strcasecmp(it->attribute(attrName).second.c_str(), attrContent.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "I FOUNDED THIS TAG = DIV WITH ATTR = CLASS" << std::endl;
            ++it;
            if ((!it->isTag()) && (!it->isComment()))
            {
                std::cout << std::endl;
                std::cout << it->text() << std::endl;
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
            //goto Exit;
        }
    }

    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < dom.number_of_children(it); i++ )
    {
        walk_tree( dom.child(it,i), tagName, attrName, attrContent);
    }

/*Exit:
    return;*/
}
```

Жду ваших комментариев/предположений, что не так с этой библиотекой!!!